# Udemy courses on salesforce

Tags: trailhead, learning

Please feel free to move this to meta/close in case you find this inappropriate in SFSE forum.

I love trailheads, three cheers for the content and effort.

Udemy is offering a lot of courses related to certifications and lightning, has anyone in this forum taken their course work? Do you find the content any different than trailheads?

https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=salesforce&src=ukw

Answer (score 3):

I have taken 2 Udemy salesforce courses.  I found the best way to start off though would be to take advantage of the trailhead material.  The Udemy courses gave a decent overview but were focused more on preparing you for certification. If you decide to take a Udemy course I would only use it as supplemental material to the salesforce documentation and wait until you preparing for certification.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!